# How to remove duplicate rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried to remove duplicate rows from a table TT

here is my query

```
delete t1 
  from TT t1
     , TT t2 
 where t1.id < t2.id 
   and t1.url = t2.url
```

Here id is the primary key and url has the unique key in the table TT. You must be wondering why there are duplicate rows with unique index?

Actually it did happen and I don't know why but right now I want to remove the duplicate rows first. I am able to run the query in phpmyadmin but no duplicate rows are deleted at all(There is duplicate rows in the Table TT).

What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I also tried to use join in the query even before I used the query I already posted. Here is the query,
[code]
delete t1 from TT t1
inner join TT t2 
where t1.id < t2.id and t1.url = t2.url
[/code]
But it still does not the job as I expected. No duplicate rows have been removed. I guess does it have anything to do with privilege in phpmyadmin? I did login in as a root user and I checked I have the all the rights. Thanks.

Comment: If *url has the unique key in the table TT* then there are no duplicates. Check again for blank not visible chars in the column.

Comment: Before I tried to remove the duplicate rows, I called the following query to check the duplicate rows, [code]
select url from TT group by url having count(id) > 1 [/code]
It did return duplicate url. Thanks.

Comment: If you really have duplicate unique indexes then that seems like a bigger problem than how to remove them. You'll never be able to trust your data.

Comment: As a side note. If I move my mouse over the query, phpmyadmin did show there is an error "Unexpected token.(near t1)". But I am still able to run the query but it just doesn't remove the duplicate rows. So I am just wondering if the innocent looking query might not be syntax correct especially in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I will definitely handle why there are still duplicate rows with unique index next. But at this time I need to remove duplicate rows first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to remove duplicate

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY url ORDER BY url) AS rn
    FROM TT
)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: Note that window functions requires MySQL 8.0.2, and not everyone has upgraded yet.